# React mapping arrays to anchor tags

Tags: reactjs

I want to map resultInfo to produce anchor tags where the first element in each array is in between the tag and the href is the second element in each array.

```
 const results = data.query.search.map((option) => [
      option.title,
      option.url
    ]);
    setResultInfo(results);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={searchQuery}>
        <input placeholder='search wikipedia' onChange={searchField}></input>
        <input type='image' value='search'></input>
      </form>
      {resultInfo.map(() => {})}
    </div>
  );
};
```

};

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Currently the callback function passed to `.map()` is empty and returns nothing.  If you want it to return an anchor tag, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I have. I tried nesting another map function inside this function to iterate over the arrays within the results array but I get a weird output. When I didn't use arrays inside of results and just had title strings I was able to put them as tags on the page, but I can't figure out how to do that once the string is nested in an array.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem in your attempt?  In general, if you're just asking how to use `.map()`, then how you use it is to call it on an array and in the callback you'd return something for each element of that array.

Answer (score 0):

Your curly brackets don't match up, making it hard to tell what's actually going on, but by the looks of it you are setting resultsInfo to a new array on every render, regardless of whether `data.query.search` has changed.

Wouldn't it make more sense to just map the `data.query.search` array, rather than creating a derived `results` state array?

In which case, you could remove the first 6 lines of your example, and simply do:

```
{data.query.search.map((option, index) => (
    <a key={index} href={option.url}>{option.title}</a>
))}
```

in place of `{resultInfo.map(() => {})}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What's going on is I can't access resultInfo in the html if I don't set it to state.